# How to compute $(1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots 97)^2 \pmod {101}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to compute $(1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5  \cdots 97)^2 \pmod {101}$ in easiest and fastest way?

Comment: You should show us your own thoughs/work on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the only tool you currently have is the Wilson's Theorem, which says that if $p$ is a prime then $$(p-1)!\equiv-1(\mathrm{mod}~p)$$

Notice that $101$ is a prime, and $1\equiv-100(\mathrm{mod}~101),~3\equiv-98(\mathrm{mod}~101),\cdots$. Hence,
$$(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots97)^{2}\equiv(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots97)(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots97)\equiv(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots97)(-100\cdot-98\cdot-96\cdots-4)(\mathrm{mod}~101)$$

Now can you finish up?

Comment: +1 Neat. I guess you also have to notice that $198=202-4$, so $25\cdot198=1\bmod101$